# IFR to VFR Flight Plan Change

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, visual-flight-rules

A pilot has filed an IFR flight plan.  While airborne, he feels like changing to VFR flight. Can he request for it and what are the conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if in VMC a pilot can cancel IFR, then request VFR flight following for the remainder of the trip.

Comment: Yes, but requesting flight following is always optional.